# All k-notes erased

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I installed [k-notes widget](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/business/knoteswidget.html) a few weeks ago and liked the concept at first.
Just a few days ago I decided to consolidate all my notes into one system and to use k-notes. I used their multiple colors to organize my notes in categories.

Today I had to reboot my MBA and noticed, to my dismay, that all purple notes are empty! I.e. the notes are still there but without any text in them!

First I was shocked, but then I realized that since I keep regular TimeMachine backups, I should have everything backed up on the external drive. But I just spent an hour searching my Air and can't find the place where k-notes stores everything.

Answer (score 1):

I also use k-notes and have had this happen once before. It happened again right before the weekend, and I have just fixed it again.

The file you want is in ~/Library/Preferences/ and is named widget-com.rakoth.lichlord.widget.k-notes.plist

I recommend going into Time Machine, selecting this file, and hitting command-option-i -- in the inspector window, pay attention to the byte size of the file. Then go back in time until you see a big jump in the file byte size. That will be your uncorrupted plist. Restore it.

Then restart your computer. I tried several times to restore it and then only restart the dashboard, but then bringing up the dashboard again only caused more corruption and blank notes. Restarting the computer gave me no corruption when I brought up the dashboard.